# play background music while playing video

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I need to know is this: can I build an app that plays music once another video with sound is opened?

For ex. I put music on my ipod inside the iphone and can close it out and it plays anytime I open another app.

However, when I open youtube or any type of site like that and hit a video, the music on my iphone cuts off. 
I want an app that allows the music to keep playng. 
The design and all other parts of app are going to be simple. 
Please advise if this is possible?

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible to the extent you would hope for. There is a 10 minute limit for how long you can run your app in the background. So you could go into the app, have **your** app play music, and when you go to youtube or whatever and it would keep playing for up to 10 minutes. But that's probably not what you're hoping for, so the quick answer is no, you can't.